# Calculation with bigz class

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to calculate some eulerian number in r. I've found the package gmp with the function "eulerian" that appears to do this. However, the return value is in the class bigz and I can't seem to extract this value to do simple calculations(multiplications etc.) with other none-bigz values. Is there a way to extract it or other work arounds? I've tried to use result$bigz, result[1] etc.

My function:

```
    library(gmp)

    Qfun <- function(l,r,n){  choose(2^l + n - r, n)/(2^(l*n)) }

    TV <- function(l,n){
    d <- 0
      for(r in 1:n){
      d <- d + Eulerian(n, r-1) * abs(Qfun(l,r,n) - 1/factorial(n))
      }
    d <- 0.5 * d
    return(d)
    }

    TV(5,52)
```

Comment: Have you tried `as.numeric(TV(5, 52))`?

Comment: It seems to work using as.numeric on the Eulerian function. Does it still use all the digits after the conversion?  it's only displaying very few digits.

Comment: I think its better if you change the other numbers to bigz with `as.bigz`.

Comment: If you want to do calculations that will involve non-integer values, you may have to load `Rmpfr` and convert to high-precision `mpfr` numbers